# Why angular modules can use dependencies of other modules?

Tags: angularjs

I have a main angular module called app. And it is dependent on 'app.items' module, which is also dependent on ngResource. So it can call some backend routes in its' services using the service with uses $resource.

Also I have another module called 'app.categories' and the main module also uses it as a dependency. That module has a category service which sends requests to backend using $resource. But when I remove 'ngResource' dependency from 'app.categories' module, it still works.

Why does that happen? Isn't that the wrong behaviour?

Comment: I think repeating dependencies are included only once and every one uses that dependency.. the problem occurs when there are conflicts between two dependencies and in this case, I think the module specific dependency gets loaded for that specific module

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think, you can get the answer from [this](http://henriquat.re/modularizing-angularjs/modularizing-angular-applications/modularizing-angular-applications.html) link

Answer (score 0):

When you say it's wrong behaviour, what do you base that on? It's only wrong if the AngularJS team didn't intend it that way.

I agree that you could say that it would be desirable for a framework or language to deny access to functionality defined in modules referenced by a referenced module, because removing the reference in module C would break module A.

However, AngularJS, for whatever reason, does not work that way. This can be found in [the source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a0b5e1a85893f65a45f6c776b5a8a2ef96be9580/src/auto/injector.js#L744), it finds all modules and referenced modules recursively, and runs the providers (controllers, services, et cetera) and `module.config` blocks per module and finally runs all `module.run` blocks.

Comment: Removing components is exactly what should be considered when designing such a behavior. Imagine that there are some dependencies that might be removed when you remove some module but still be used in other modules and then be unnoticed for a long time and then a developer won't even know, what was the exact reason of an error thrown.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I don't think you can call AngularJS's behaviour wrong. Lots of languages and frameworks work differently from each other, and I wouldn't call any one of them absolutely wrong or absolutely right. They're just different, and you can choose which one you choose to work in.